# Julia: U factor in Cholesky factorization is not a field?

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

Suppose that I have the following

```
> L = [5 1; 1 3]

> chol = LinearAlgebra.cholesky(L)
LinearAlgebra.Cholesky{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}
U factor:
2×2 LinearAlgebra.UpperTriangular{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}:
 2.23607  0.447214
  ⋅       1.67332
```

I want to access the matrix and more specifically slice the matrix and get the first row, second row, etc, so I can access the factor `U` like this

```
> chol.U
2×2 LinearAlgebra.UpperTriangular{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}:
 2.23607  0.447214
  ⋅       1.67332
```

My question is: what exactly does `.U` stand for? If I try `getfield(chol, :U)` I get an error because there is no field `:U` and indeed, `fieldnames(LinearAlgebra.Cholesky)` returns `:factors`, `:uplo` and `:info`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Julia 1.0 the dot syntax `x.s` is shorthand for `getproperty(x, :s)` just like `x[idx]` maps to `getindex(x, idx)`. Hence, you can make it behave in whatever way you want. Only the generic default is equivalent to lettings you access an object's fields. To see the particular method that is called for objects of type `Cholesky` you can use `@which` as follows:

```
julia> @which chol.U
getproperty(C::Cholesky, d::Symbol) in LinearAlgebra at C:\cygwin\home\Administrator\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\LinearAlgebra\src\cholesky.jl:339
```

If you check the source code in [cholesky.jl:339](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/d76101d0edad873a500206898809cf4de96dcd7b/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/src/cholesky.jl#L338) you find the following:

```
function getproperty(C::Cholesky, d::Symbol)
    Cfactors = getfield(C, :factors)
    Cuplo    = getfield(C, :uplo)
    info     = getfield(C, :info)
    if d == :U
        return UpperTriangular(Cuplo === char_uplo(d) ? Cfactors : copy(Cfactors'))
    elseif d == :L
        return LowerTriangular(Cuplo === char_uplo(d) ? Cfactors : copy(Cfactors'))
    elseif d == :UL
        return (Cuplo === 'U' ? UpperTriangular(Cfactors) : LowerTriangular(Cfactors))
    else
        return getfield(C, d)
    end
end
```

We see that in the case `d == :U` it does not map to something like `getfield(C, d)` but instead constructs a `UpperTriangular` matrix in some way. Only for some generic symbol `d` does the method map to `getfield(C, d)`.

Lastly, the pendant of `fieldnames` for fields is `propertynames` for properties (things that you can write for `s` in `x.s`):

```
julia> propertynames(chol)
(:U, :L, :UL)

julia> fieldnames(typeof(chol))
(:factors, :uplo, :info)
```

As you can see the two concepts, fields and properties, can be orthogonal. In this case, there is no direct overlap.

Comment: Hmm, I see.. I had never encountered the concept of property before. Is a property only defined through the `getproperty` method? And does this mean that properties do not "live" anywhere (as opposed to fields living inside the `struct`)?

Comment: They are defined through `propertynames`, `getproperty`, and `setproperty!`. Yes, if you will, they do not "live" anywhere.

Comment: However, generically and typically they have 100% overlap with fields.